# Angular PrimeNG p-dialog with tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, primeng

I am using primeng to create a dialog with tabs, this is my template:

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="displayDialog" (onHide)="cancel()" [style]="{width: '50vw'}" [baseZIndex]="10000">
  <p-tabView [controlClose]="displayDialog">
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 1" [headerStyle]='{"width": "70px"}'>Text 1</p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 2" [headerStyle]='{"width": "70px"}'> Text 2</p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 3" [headerStyle]='{"width": "70px"}'>Tex 3</p-tabPanel>
  </p-tabView>
</p-dialog>
```

I get this as a result

[image]

However, I would like to have it like Angular Material: (matDialog)

[image]

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Is there a way to have it like Angular Material using PrimeNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PrimeNG supports [Material theme](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/setup). These are the Material themes (with prefix: **md**):

> primeng/resources/themes/md-light-indigo/theme.css
>
> primeng/resources/themes/md-light-deeppurple/theme.css
>
> primeng/resources/themes/md-dark-indigo/theme.css
>
> primeng/resources/themes/md-dark-deeppurple/theme.css
>
> primeng/resources/themes/mdc-light-indigo/theme.css
>
> primeng/resources/themes/mdc-light-deeppurple/theme.css
>
> primeng/resources/themes/mdc-dark-indigo/theme.css
>
> primeng/resources/themes/mdc-dark-deeppurple/theme.css

Hence, you don't need to switch the PrimeNG component to the Angular Material component as you can adopt the Material theme.

---

You can import desired Material theme by:

### Solution 1: Add theme to angular.json

> angular.json

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/md-light-indigo/theme.css"
]
```

[Sample Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rkhp8w)

---

### Solution 2: Import theme to the global stylesheet

> style.css

```
@import 'primeng/resources/themes/md-light-indigo/theme.css';
```

[Sample Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m9ekvq)

Comment: You are welcome. If my solution helps you, please upvote/accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: yes. Just one more question, is there a way to center the tabs?  by default they are aligned to the left, I would like to display them in the center

Comment: You may check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dymlow?file=src/app/dialog/dialog.component.css).

Comment: Great :) Thank you!